# WebStorm "Before Launch" – Wait for completion

Tags: npm, webpack, ide, webstorm

I am trying to set up this (more than slightly ridiculous) stack:

- Bundler: Webpack
- Library: ReactJS
- Language: TypeScript + JSX (tsx)
- IDE: WebStorm

Now, this was all working fine, until I realized that my app wasn't being compiled by WebStorm unless I manually ran the `webpack` command before running the app.

What I tried next was editing my Run/Debug Configuration (JavaScript Debug) to run `webpack` as an External Tool "*Before* Launch". Note the "*Before*".

This was all working fine, too, until I **then** realized that WebStorm was asynchronously *starting* `webpack` and running the app immediately after starting, meaning that none of the changes since the last compile were saved (since `webpack` didn't have time to finish compiling before the app was run)!

"Simple", thought my naïve self, "all I must do is toggle the 'Wait For Completion' checkbox, which surely must exist!" But as is always the case, that was not the case. I could find no such checkbox.

~30 minutes and a few brain cells later, here I am. Now, the question is:

### How do I get my Webpack application to be compiled *before* it is run in WebStorm?

---

What I **have** tried so far:

- Adding the `webpack` command to the "Before launch" section of my Run/Debug configuration. As described above, WebStorm does not wait for it to complete before running the app, causing the previous version to be run instead.
- Configuring a NPM `build` script to simply run `webpack`, then adding *that* to the "Before launch" section. Same problem. Now I'm starting to wonder if *anything* in the "Before launch" section is run synchronously...

What I **have not** tried so far (and why):

- Creating a custom NPM `run` script that runs `webpack` then starts the debugger. This is far from ideal because (as far as I know) it would be extremely difficult to make this work with the WebStorm debugger.
- Manually running `webpack` each time before debugging. Well, I have tried it and it works; but I hope it's pretty clear why this is not a good long-term solution.
- Manually including each script in my HTML. As the app grows, I may have many more scripts, and I am **not** looking forward to adding each one manually to HTML just so I can debug them easier.

***I am open to any solutions, including those suggesting alternatives to Webpack*** (but any alternatives to WebStorm, ReactJS, or Typescript must be REALLY good because I have already put a lot of thought into picking those).

Comment: WebStorm waits for the exit code 0 from the Before launch task (that is, for example, a npm task) before it starts the main configuration. Is there an exit code in the Run tool window with the npm build task in the IDE?

Comment: Yes, the process exits fine, but WebStorm starts running the app before it exits, as I said in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue, please follow [WEB-21022](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21022) for updates. Problem is not specific to webpack, and the only workaround is running webpack manually (via run configuration or external tool) before starting the app. Note that I can't recreate it when debugging, only when running the application

Comment: Same for me. Clicking Debug button - works as expected: IDE waits for Before Run tasks to complete with exit code 0 and then opens URL in a browser. Clicking Run button: IDE doesn't wait for Before Run tasks. Bug tracked as WEB-21022.